# Why does is_convertible<EnumClass, int> return false?

Tags: c++, enums, type-traits

I don't understand why `std::is_convertible_v<EnumClass, int>` returns false in this example, especially given that `static_cast<int>(enumClassValue)` works correctly.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

enum Enum {X = 5};
enum class EnumClass {X = 5};

int main() {
    Enum enumValue = Enum::X;
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(enumValue) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_convertible_v<Enum, int> << std::endl;

    EnumClass enumClassValue = EnumClass::X;
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(enumClassValue) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_convertible_v<EnumClass, int> << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: static_cast is an explicit conversion, is_convertible_v checks for the ability to implicitly convert from one type to another. Also `enum` is (almost) an int, while `enum class` is a distinct type (and thus should be used in C++ if you want type safety)

Comment: When doing `static_cast` you're forcing the compiler to do the conversion.

Comment: indeed the name `is_convertible` is somewhat confusing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::is_convertible_v<From, To>` returns `true` if a value of type `From` is *implicitly* convertible to type `To`.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible

> If the imaginary function definition `To test() { return std::declval<From>(); }` is well-formed, (that is, either `std::declval<From>()` can be converted to `To` using implicit conversions, or both `From` and `To` are possibly cv-qualified `void`), provides the member constant value equal to `true`. Otherwise value is `false`.

Values of `enum class` types (unlike regular `enum`s) require an explicit conversion to perform that conversion; hence, the valued returned by `is_convertible_v` is correct.

Answer (score 4):

In the latter case you have a *scoped enum*, which isn't implicitly convertible to an integer. This can be seen from [enum declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum):

> **There are no implicit conversions from the values of a scoped enumerator to integral types**, although static_cast may be used to obtain the numeric value of the enumerator.

---

On the other hand, an unscoped enum does allow implicit conversion, so the observed behavior.

From [implicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion):

> A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is not fixed can be converted to a prvalue of the first type from the following list able to hold their entire value range:
>
> - int
> - ...